# how to search for a value having alphanumeric character from a varchar2 column in DB2

Tags: db2

I am having records like 001A,002B i need to retrive value based on numeric value i.e,for 001 it should show both 001A and 001B value.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in DB2 to define your values. You call them with xQuery.

Comment: i dn't hv idea on xQuery if u can give sm detail much appreciated

Comment: Check these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553807/db2-find-field-value-where-first-character-is-a-lower-case-letter/21554999#21554999 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712132/emulate-regexp-like-behaviour-in-sql/23341456#23341456

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column like '001%'
```

Comment: thx for answering bt i want a general case, no only m having all the records staring 001 sm recods like 2543A,2543B and so on.....

Comment: @Ansuman: Based on your question as it is now, the above statement does exactly what you asked for. If you want something else you need to provide more detail.

Comment: i tested this query bt unble to get desired result ok so in details like there are records like 2718632A,2718632B one 2718632 have 2 value like A and B i want to search giving numeric only i.e 2718632 it should give me 2 value and am having records like 28736A,28736B-00126A,00126B and so on..

Comment: @Ansuman - so replace `'001%'` with `'2718632%'`?  Are you trying to search multiple values at a time?  If so, where are they coming from?